# Callback after all animates done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-deferred

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/dqmf5/3/)

I need help making callback after all `animate` methods inside `do_animations` are done. For one `animate` i could call `promise` and `done` function. I tried using `$.Callbacs` but i don't know how to make promise object from `fire` method.

```
function random_num(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a;
}

function do_animations() {
    var n = random_num(1, 5);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var width = random_num(-50, 50);
        $('#rec').animate({'left': '+=' + width + 'px'}, 300);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    do_animations();
});
```

Best solution would be

```
do_animations().done(function(){ ... });
```

Comment: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — **in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using promise():

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dqmf5/10/)

```
function do_animations() {
    var n = random_num(1, 5),
        $rec = $('#rec');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var width = random_num(-50, 50);
        $rec.animate({'left': '+=' + width + 'px'}, 300);
    }
    return $rec.promise();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    do_animations().done(function(){ alert("All animations done!") });
});
```

Comment: This looks really great. Do you think it would be hard to change for multi objects animations?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have any issue but depending what are multiple targeted elements and how you handle them

Comment: For instance, animate would concerns #rec and #ring objects. Maybe i could make some array and call promise on it ?

Comment: you could try: `return $('#rec').add('#ring').promise();`  http://jsfiddle.net/dqmf5/11/

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly. I will read more about deferred and promise object, i can `promise()` you that ;)